# Tag someone in a comment

Tags: support, comment-replies

I want to tag the person who answered a section of my question and check with him as to how I must proceed. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean using [comment replies](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info)? (I have to admit that I do not understand your question.)

Comment: Yes. I tried using "@" but it didn't show the tag.

Comment: Were you posting the comment under the users answer and `@username` was automatically removed? This is done on purpose and the user will be pinged. See, for example: [Comment error while posting comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/comment-error-while-posting-comments)

Comment: Ah ok :) Thanks

Comment: This explains in detail the cases when using `@username` is not needed: [When is @ ping necessary to cause comment notification to take place?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/when-is-ping-necessary-to-cause-comment-notification-to-take-place)

Comment: Oh ok :) Great! Thanks :)